# Splitting the header in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset which has all the headers written in a continuous format (in the very first cell of the file) without any delimiter and with names having varying length, which looks something like this:

```
ABCDEFG
1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
```

I would like the dataset to look something like this:

```
AB C D EFG
1  0 1 0
0  0 1 0
1  1 0 1
```

With every column getting its respective header name. How can I do this?

Comment: Run `print(df.columns)`. Please paste what is printed out.

Comment: Do you have any kind of way to determine where you should cut the names ? If you don't it will be pretty hard to do it automatically...

Comment: That's where the problem comes in, unfortunately the header names are varying in length and dont have a specific format.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ after running "print(df.columns)" i get all the column names something like this "path_id\tarrival_days\t..."

Comment: @Sahil You have major issues with the way you read in your data frame, but that's for a different question. I think this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

If your header is something like that:

```
header = ['ABCDEFG']
```

Based on index, you can write:

```
header = [header[0][:2], header[0][2], header[0][3], header[0][4:]]
```

You get:

```
['AB', 'C', 'D', 'EFG']
```

Comment: I don't recommend blindly hardcoding the sequence like this.

Comment: @coldspeed Agree, but you solution with slices could be an obscure solution…

Comment: Also, you are assuming the header is a one item list, which is wrong... and your whole solution falls apart if that is not the case.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ he is not assuming anything. Given what OP has shown in his post he is answering based on that. If a more complex question is presented or OP specifies it as so then yes this answer is not valid, but otherwise this does as good of a job as yours at answering the question.

Comment: @aws_apprentice "_Given what OP has shown in his post he is answering based on that._" That's called making an assumption

Comment: I am not here to argue with you. This answer is equally as valid as yours.

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how your columns currently are, you can first join them and the resplit using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import islice

seq = [2, 1, 1, 3]
it = iter(''.join(df.columns))
df.columns = [''.join(islice(it, 0, i)) for i in seq]
```

This assigns `['AB', 'C', 'D', 'EFG']` to `df.columns`. The advantage of this technique is you can control the size and number of splits nicely simply by editing the `seq` list, and *nothing else*.